# Entity Framework Many-to-Many LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two models with a many to many relationship:

`Example` and `Sample`. In the database, EF creates three tables:

```
Examples  
Samples  
ExampleSamples
```

I am trying to select all Examples from `ExampleSamples`, where Samples Id is IN a list of Sample Ids.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that I would do it:

```
var sampleids = new int[]{1,2,3};
var examples = db.Examples.Where(e=>e.Samples.Any(s=>sampleids.Contains(s.id));
```

You can also do a Intersect instead of Any/Contains, and you can also do it via a SelectMany, but this I think is the easiest to understand.

Comment: Thanks Robert, appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for many to many where the connecting list only contains the PKs from the two tables in the many-to-many:

```
int[,] courseIDs = new int[,] { 1,2,3 };
var students =
 from s in dc.Students
 from c in s.Courses
 where courseIDs.Contains(c.CourseID)
 select s;
```

https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/